# Approximation property of Fréchet if range is restricted to an embedded Hilbert space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, approximation-theory

Let $W$ be a separable Fréchet space, and $H\subset W$ be a separable Hilbert space that is continuously embedded (equivalently, the topology of $H$ is stronger than the subspace topology generated by the topology of $W$).

It is known that there exists an increasing sequence of finite dimensional subspaces $F_n$ such that the orthogonal projection $\pi_n: H\to F_n$ extends by continuity to $W$, and the union of all $F_n$ is dense in $H$ (and therefore also in $W$).

Can these subspaces be chosen in such a way that $\pi_n x\to x$ with respect to the topology of $W$ for all $x\in W$ as $n\to\infty$? If needed, it may be assumed that the embedding of $H$ in $W$ is compact (that is, the closed unit ball of $H$ is a compact subset of $W$).

Comment: No, not even if $W$ is a Banach space.  What you want implies that $W$ has the bounded approximation property.

Comment: @Bill Johnsen: Thanks for your comment. I am aware it does. The existence of a dense Hilbert space (which has the metric approximation property) does not imply this?

Comment: No. For any separable, infinite dimensional Banach space $X$, there is a one to one compact operator from $\ell_2$ into $X$ that has dense range.  This is a simple exercise.

Comment: @Bill Johnson: Thanks for pointing this out. Indeed, such a space is constructed easily.